# ng-repeat : ng-model problem adding new element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have I form of inputs and using ng-repeat I add new inputs fields dinamically with button.
Each input is already completed by "text".

The problem :

When I insert new input field by button, the first input field clean out text.

I verify in my browser debugger and first element of my Items Array is not empty. Why it is not present on input ?

There is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input ng-repeat="item in vm.myItemsArray" 
        name="myItemName" 
        class="form-control" 
        type="text" 
        ng-model="item.value"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <span ng-click="addItem()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-sm btn-default"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

AND JS :

```
// INITIALIZE INPUTS
vm.myItemsArray = [{value: "text"}];

// ADD NEW INPUTS
function addItem() {
    vm.myItemsArray.push({value: "text"});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('angularExampleModule',[])
        .controller('angularExampleController', ['$scope', angularExampleController]);

    function angularExampleController($scope){
      $scope.myItemsArray = [{value: "text"}];
      $scope.addItem = function () {
       $scope.myItemsArray.push({value: "text"});
      }
}
})();
```

```css
.input-element{
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularExampleModule" ng-controller="angularExampleController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 input-element" ng-repeat="item in myItemsArray">
        <input name="myItemName" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.value"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
    <button ng-click="addItem()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-sm btn-default">Add Item</button>
 
    </div>
</div>
```

OR Check this https://codepen.io/DeepaliK/pen/BqXqNB